# What does mean : element of $L^p$ are equivalence class rather than function.

Tags: lp-spaces

What does mean : An element of $L^p$ is rather an equivalent class that a function ? If $f\in L^p$, why don't we see it as a function (it's always what I did until now, but why is it not totally correct ?) What is the subtlety with these "equivalent class" ?

Comment: If you define a function in $L^p$, it's defined up to a set of measure $0$. I.e. if $f(x)=e^{-x^2}$ in $L^p$, this mean that $f(x)=e^{-x^2}$ a.e. The problem of this definition, it's if you fix a $x$, you don't really know what is $f(x)$. You cannot really evaluate the function at a given point.

Answer (score 6):

Let's say you have a measurable function $f \colon X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ on $(X,\mu,\Sigma)$. You can say two distinct things about $f$:

1. The function $f$ is $p$-integrable meaning $\int_X |f|^p d\mu < \infty$. Let's denote the space of $p$-integrable functions on $X$ by $L^p(X,\mu, \Sigma)$.
2. The function $f$ "belongs to $L^p$". This is actually an abuse of terminology since the space $L^p$ is not a space of functions but a space of equivalence classes
   $$ \mathcal{L}^p(X,\mu,\Sigma) := L^p(X,\mu,\Sigma) / \sim $$
   where $f \sim g$ if and only if $f - g = 0$ a.e. That is, when you say that $f$ belongs to $\mathcal{L}^p$, you actually mean that $[f] \in \mathcal{L}^p(X,\mu,\Sigma)$.

The reason the $\mathcal{L}^p$ spaces are defined as a quotient of actual $p$-integrable functions $L^p$ by an equivalence relation and not just as the spaces of $p$-integrable functions is that you want to turn them into normed vector spaces using the norm

$$ \| f \|_p = \left(\int_X |f|^p \, du\right)^{1/p}. $$

This is not a norm on $L^p$ but only a semi-norm since it is possible that $\| f \|_p = 0$ even though $f \neq 0$. By taking the quotient, the semi-norm descends to an honest-to-god norm on the quotient space $\mathcal{L}^p$.

---

Thus, an element $f \in L^p(X,\mu,\Sigma)$ is an actual function on $X$ so you can talk about (say) the value of $f$ at a point $x \in X$. However, an element $[f] \in \mathcal{L}^p(X,\mu,\Sigma)$ is not a function on $X$ but an equivalence class of functions on $X$ and so (say) the value of $[f]$ at a point $x \in X$ doesn't make sense (since it is possible that $[f] = [g]$ but $f(x) \neq g(x)$ so the operation of evaluating an equivalence class at a point $x \in X$ is not well-defined).

Comment: Thank you for this answer, which is extremely insightful!

Answer (score 3):

This kind of thing occurs frequently in mathematics.

You may say a "rational number" $\frac{7}{12}$ is not the pair $(7,12)$, but rather an **equivalence class** of such pairs, so that $\frac{7}{12}=\frac{-7}{-12}=\frac{21}{36}=\dots$.

You may say that a "real number" is an **equivalence class** of Cauchy sequences of rational numbers, where we allow two different Cauchy sequences to  represent the same real number.  Agreed, this can be confusing, judging from all he questons about whether $0.\overline{9} = 1$ or not.

You may say that $\mathbb C = \mathbb R [X]/(X^2+1)$, so that a complex numbr is an equivalence class of polynomials over the reals.  For beginners, we may disguise this by saying: "A complex number is of the form $a+bi$ and for computations use the ordinary rules together with $i^2=-1$".

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand why $7/12$ is an equivalence class, neither why a real number is an equivalence class with Cauchy sequence... neither why $\mathbb C=\{a+ib\mid a,b\in\mathbb R\}$ is an equivalent class... and this form is only for beginner with $i^2=-1$. It's not true that $\mathbb C=\{a+ib\mid a,b\in\mathbb R\}$ ? uuggghhh...

Comment: There are several ways to construct $\mathbb{C}$, you can even represent complex numbers by matrices. But I think it should appear clearly to you that if we define $C$ by a quotient field, the elements of this field are equivalence classes. The other examples may require some hindsight on the question.

Answer (score 1):

Let $(X,{\cal A},\mu)$ be a measure space, and let $\mu^*$ be the completion of $\mu.$ IF $f,g\colon X\longrightarrow\mathbb R$ are measurable functions, we usually identify $f$ with $g$ when the set $\{x\in X\,|\,f(x)\neq g(x)\}$ has null $\mu^*$-measure. This identification is actually an equivalence relation. Thanks to it, it is true that$$\lVert f-g\rVert_p=0\iff f\sim g,$$where $\sim$ is the equivalence relation that I have described. Otherwise, we could have distinct functions such that the distance between them would be $0$. That is, $\bigl(L^p(\mu),\lVert\cdot\rVert_p\bigr)$ would *not* be a normed-vector space.

Comment: I understand the "reason" of the relation $f=g$ a.e., what I don't understand it's element in $L^p$ are not really functions... For me there are functions, and I don't really understand why they would not be functions... (thank you for your answer btw)

Comment: @NewMath: As I said in my comment below your question : If $f$ is defined in $L^p$ (i.e. up to a set of measure 0), you can't evaluate $f$ at a given point.

Comment: Here why we need to discuss in completion of measure?